# Youtube Api - iframe вместо div player

Tags: javascript, html, dom, javascript-events

Нужно на `html` страницу вставить `youtube` `iframe`.
Именно через тэг `iframe`.

В официальной документации сказано, что есть 2 способа

1. `<div id="player"></div>`
2. заменить `div` тэгом `iframe`

Я заменил, но к сожалению события не работают когда вместо `div` на странице `iframe`.

Событие `onPlayerReady` выводит сообщение `ready`, если `iframe` сменить на `div` будет работать, наоборот не хочет, не понимаю в чем проблема.

```js
// 2. This code loads the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.
var tag = document.createElement('script');

tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

// 3. This function creates an <iframe> (and YouTube player)
//    after the API code downloads.
var player;
var videoId = '2Vv-BfVoq4g';
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
  //   alert('test');

  player = new YT.Player('player', {
    height: '360',
    width: '640',
    videoId: videoId,
    events: {
      'onReady': onPlayerReady,
      'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
    }
  });


}

// 4. The API will call this function when the video player is ready.
function onPlayerReady(event) {
    alert('ready');
  event.target.playVideo(); //auto play video
}

// 5. The API calls this function when the player's state changes.
//    The function indicates that when playing a video (state=1),
//    the player should play for six seconds and then stop.
var done = false;
function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
  if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING && !done) {
    setTimeout(stopVideo, 6000);
    done = true;
  }
}
function stopVideo() {
  player.stopVideo();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<iframe id="player" type="text/html" width="640" height="360"
  src="//www.youtube.com/embed/M7lc1UVf-VE?enablejsapi=1&origin=http://example.com"
  frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Уберите параметр `origin` из `src iframe`, либо подставь туда свой домен и будет вам счастье)

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<iframe id="player" width="640" height="360"
        src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/M7lc1UVf-VE?enablejsapi=1"
        frameborder="0"></iframe>
<script>
    // 2. This code loads the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.
    var tag = document.createElement('script');

    tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
    var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

    // 3. This function creates an <iframe> (and YouTube player)
    //    after the API code downloads.
    var player;
    var videoId = '2Vv-BfVoq4g';
    function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
        //   alert('test');

        player = new YT.Player('player', {
            height: '360',
            width: '640',
            videoId: videoId,
            events: {
                'onReady': onPlayerReady,
                'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
            }
        });


    }

    // 4. The API will call this function when the video player is ready.
    function onPlayerReady(event) {
        alert('ready');
        event.target.playVideo(); //auto play video
    }

    // 5. The API calls this function when the player's state changes.
    //    The function indicates that when playing a video (state=1),
    //    the player should play for six seconds and then stop.
    var done = false;
    function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
        if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING && !done) {
            setTimeout(stopVideo, 6000);
            done = true;
        }
    }
    function stopVideo() {
        player.stopVideo();
    }
</script>
```

Comment: спасибо, добрый человек )